# Find the index of a div inside a container

Tags: javascript, html, indexing

I have a container with multiple divs and in each div I have a handler on which you can click.
The requirement is to return the index of the div in the container for further processing.
I've simplified the code for readability purposes.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    
    <div class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript code I tried so far but I always get `-1` as the index:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.handler').click(function(e) {
        let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call($('.container'), $(this).parents('.block'));
        console.log(index);
  });
});
```

I also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36rhcqm5/1/).

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
$('.handler').click(function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    console.log([].indexOf.call(el.parentNode.parentNode.children, el.parentNode));
});
```

However if you want to know what was wrong in your code,

```
Array.prototype.indexOf.call($('.container')[0].children, $(this).parents('.block')[0])
```

This part should fix the problem in your code. You have been doing it all right, but for the parameter of `indexOf` we needed the children array of `.container` and clicked element.

You were passing the container element and current clicked element as an array. That is `Array.prototype.indexOf.call('[Container Element]', ['current clicked div'])` Which is not right. You should pass something like this,
`Array.prototype.indexOf.call('[children, children, children...]', 'current clicked div element')`.

It was happening because the `$('.container')` returns an array with the element having a class name .container. But we needed all the children array of the element that contains container class.

And `$(this).parents('.block')` returns an array with the matching elements even if it is only one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this. Find the index of the closest element of the clicked element, which is also a direct child of `.handler`. To find index, use `index()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.handler').click(function(e) {
    let index = $(this).closest('.block').index()
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">

    <div class="handler">
      Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">

    <div class="handler">
      Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">

    <div class="handler">
      Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">

    <div class="handler">
      Click
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the index using the index method on parent element of selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.handler').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).parent().index())
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking at the wrong level of nesting in your HTML. I believe what you're trying to do is check from one level higher, at ".container" and get the index of the ".block" element that was clicked.

This code works in your Fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.handler').click(function(e) {
      const p = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      const index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(p.children, e.target.parentElement);

      console.log(p.className) // "container"
      console.log(index)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done simply using delegate in jQuery.

I modify your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64fcdr9u/8/) code.

```
$(".container").delegate('.block', 'click', function () {
    console.log( $(this).index() );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use a id

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    
    <div id='0' class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div id='1' class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div id='2' class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    
    <div id='3' class="handler">
    Click
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.handler').click(function(e) {
    let index = this.id
    console.log(index);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhrt596x/2/

Comment: There can be multiple elements, and adding id to each one of them is not a good way.

Comment: This is not an option because it would require the renumbering of the ids after deleting an element.